# Diameters of random bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, random-graphs, bipartite-graphs

Given two partite sets of vertices $U$ and $V$ of size $n$. Each vertex in $U$ uniformly randomly selects $K$ ($K$ is a constant and $K\ll n$) vertices in $V$ without replacement and connects a bidirectional edge to each of the vertices it selects. My question is, what is the expected diameter of the bipartite graph generated this way? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a particular range of $K$ you care about? E.g. $K = \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: What I focus on is the case where $K$ is a constant, such as $K=5$. Maybe my expression was not clear, sorry.

Comment: The graph is disconnected with nonzero probability, so the expected diameter is infinite. This silly thing apart, I believe that it is known that it is an expander graph with probability going to $1$ with $n$, so the typical diameter is of order $\log(n)$.